# Laravel Authentication doesnt persist - using remote table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

This has been an issue for a while now. I'm using Laravel 5.5 pretty much to build an admin panel for an existing database. The database has its own set of tables to manage and its own user table. The table is hosted remotely on an RDS instance.

I've created a new Laravel Project - I'm using a very simple authentication script - pass an id and a token as parameters to a route to sign in. So the route is as so:

`/auth/login?id=XXX&token=XXX`

My code for the controllers method is just:

`$user = \App\Models\User::find($id);
\Auth::loginUsingId($id);`

My config file refers the database on the remote server. And my User model is:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'auth_user';
    }

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

`\Auth::loginUsingId($id);` successfully logs in the user and a session is created - however the minute I refresh the page or redirect to another page - `\Auth::check()` returns `false`

I've tried pretty much everything but the session refuses to persist - the table has all the attributes required - where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a remote database, i believe its not the same IP with your platform. If you're using a file session storage you'll have a problem doing your authentication.

You may want to consider storing your session to a database server to solve your concern.

This is the simplest and fastest way to solve it. Believe me.:)

Comment: Not working - I mean multiple sessions are being created everytime - however the session created for the user is not persisting - Auth::loginUsingId creates a session - but by the time I redirect to another page its gone :(

Comment: do u redirect to another page with the same domain/subdomain? Try to put your session table to the remote database if you could do it and retry to process again .

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue when you implemented your session storage to a database for this kind of scenario. I had experienced this kind of issue that you're having few years ago. Just sharing my solution I've done and its completely working from my end up to now for all projects with external database.

Comment: Just checked - I moved my routes to the web middleware and I noticed that sessions are not persisted along a route thats just a closure which outputs a view. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Save your session to a database. This will save you a million times.